# Serialized objects/messages as types in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I was wondering if besides the primitives. It is possible to have a serialized object/message as type for a protobuf var in a message?

Comment: This is possible via the `bytes` scalar type which [_"May contain any arbitrary sequence of bytes."_](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#scalar) But just because you can does not mean you should. By doing this you're defeating the whole idea of using protobuf at all. Suddenly your API won't be strongly-typed, but dynamic in nature. The API cannot be consumed by any language and if it can, the other consumers need to explicitly know the structure of the serialized objects. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a protobuf-friendly way to do it.

Comment: I am building a server where you can store certain things. One such thing is objects of your choosing. So I when my client has a different language my idea was serialize that object wrap it server side in an object of your language and when needed send it back. Then you should be able to deserialize client side the object I believe.

Comment: Aha, makes sense. In that case if the clients are working with protos, I'd still force the clients to use protobuf, the mechanism to hold client-defined protos is the [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) type which holds any `Message` together with an URI to identify the type. If this is not good enough for them, they can always just serialize whatever into a simple `byte[]` wrapper. If your clients don't know anything about protos, your original approach seems fine.